# Excel converting Dates to American Format

Tags: excel, date, formatting

Recently my excel tables started converting dates to American Date format as default. It's very strange as the data format of the table is in "dd/mm/yyyy" but it is switching to "mm/dd/yyyy". My computer's default settings are in "dd/mm/yyyy". So I can't understand whats driving it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLl1d.png)

I have tried changing the format for the entire column to dd/mm/yyyy but the table reverts back to mm/dd/yyyy when pasting new values.

Any help on what it might be would be much appreciated. It's driving me insane as its affecting my macros

Comment: Could there be vba in a worksheet change event that would be resetting the format of the cells?

Comment: Yes, the VBA code was pasting values in the table, however, it seemed to be affecting the formatting not sure why. Was able to correct it, by changing the formatting at the source and now the issue appears to have disappeared